# ELIF SyntaxError: invalid syntax;

Tags: python

when I try to run this code:

```
 elif 'intruder alert' in command:
    speak("Diming the lights" + dim)
    danger_light() 
    speak("You came into the wrong house")
```

It gives me this:

```
elif 'intruder alert' in command:
   ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

how do I fix this I'm on Mac

Comment: `elif` has to follow an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `if` block?

```
if condition:
    pass
elif another_condition:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Yes I have a if block it looks like this  run_Spike():
   command = takeCommand()
   print(command)
   if 'play' in command:
       song = command.replace('play', '')
       speak('playing' + song)
       pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
   elif 'time' in command:
       print(time)
       speak('The Current

Comment: @Comapcked1911 update your start post to have a good code formatting